# open php page with rewriterule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I looked many guides, but can't find a solution. :'(

I have 3 pages like this:

- example.com/index.php?page=first
- example.com/index.php?page=second
- example.com/index.php?page=third

I added this simple htaccess rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

All right, it does what I want:

- example.com/first
- example.com/second
- example.com/third

Now I need to open a normal php page without rules

- example.com/test.php

if I run this, I still see the index.php...

How can I run test.php file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*).php$ /$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude your files and folder from rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: @user2078421 please mark this one correct, it is the more correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the page/file name `rewrite rule` before specifying rewrite rule of `index.php`

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule test.php /test.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

If you have move then 1 file in `.php` extension then simply replace

```
RewriteRule test.php /test.php [L]
```

with

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*).php$ /$1.php [L]
```